# Reference outlet to main NSWindow in AppDelegate (OSX)

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, appdelegate

When you create a new project, I seem to remember you being able to access the basic blank window it creates in the storyboard using `self.window` in the `AppDelegate` methods.

I can't seem to set a reference outlet to the `AppDelegate.h` file via the storyboard either. Am I just hallucinating or is there no way to access the window/controller from `AppDelegate`?

Am I mixing up iOS and OSX practices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using storyboards, it seems impossible to connect the WindowController to AppDelegate. I used the following to get a reference to the main window:

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (weak) NSWindow* window;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
            _window = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject];
    }
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690074/reference-main-nswindow-in-appdelegate-using-storyboard) for swift solution. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

It's working for me.

I added an IBOutlet to my AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
```

Then in your Interface Builder (MainMenu.xib for me) select App Delegate:

[image]

Your IBOutlet should be in the `Connection inspector` to the right:

[image]

Maybe the connection between your .xib and your AppDelegate is lost?

Comment: I've tried control clicking and dragging to my appdelegate.h file to create a reference outlet however it just won't do anything(normally that blue line would show up and id be able to create an iboutlet) I'm also using a storyboard not an .xib. This is basically a fresh cocoa app using a storyboard. I think I may just be confusing iOS basics with OSX but I feel like I should be able to just call self.window from appdelegate.m without having to do anything...

Comment: Sorry, missed your Storyboard reference in your question. I haven't used Cocoa apps with storyboard so I might not be able to help you out here.

Comment: No worries, I think I found a way around my problem without needing to access the window through appdelegate! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: did you find a solution?
im stuck here