# Reference main NSWindow in AppDelegate using Storyboard?

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, interface-builder

I am attempting to set an outlet for the main window of my app in my App Delegate, then connect it within Interface Builder. I create the outlet within my App Delegate easily:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainWindow: NSWindow!
```

However there's no way, within interface builder, for me to connect a referencing outlet to the App Delegate. Instead, I can only connect it to the Window Controller, which I hope this picture shows:

[image]

The first object is the Window Controller and the second object is the First Responder, however the App Delegate object is missing. The menubar has the App Delegate object:

[image]

And I can connect anything from the menubar to any outlets in the App Delegate.

I figure I can access the window object by using:

```
NSApp.windows[0]
```

But that seems prone to error, especially if I have more than one window.

Comment: Why do you want a reference of NSWindow in App Delegate ?

Comment: @Kaunteya I'm trying to implement `applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:` and reopen the main window if the dock icon is clicked, but I have no way to reference the main window from the App Delegate. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont know if this is correct way of doing, but this will solve your problem.

Decalre a NSWindow property in AppDelegate

```
weak var window: NSWindow!
```

and set the property in something like [windowWillLoad](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/windowWillLoad) of the NSWindowController

```
(NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window = self.window
```

You will have to subclass NSWindowController to define windowWillLoad