# Detecting When App Enters Full Screen Mode (Swift/Mac)

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I'm hoping this is a simple question, but I am trying to discern a way to figure out when a user has selected to enter Full Screen mode in an app.  Effectively, I have a table in a Cocoa app that looks rather silly when the app enters full-screen mode.  I would like to, programmatically, adjust the height of my table rows once the app enters full screen mode, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do so.

I recognize the need to use `windowWillEnterFullScreen:` and `windowDidEnterFullScreen:`, or find a way for my Window to conform to my App Delegate file, though I'm struggling to figure this out.  Are there any resources that could be provided that may be able to point in the right direction?

Thank you!

Edit:  Here's what I've tried to do;

**AppDelegate.swift**
import Cocoa

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {

var window: NSWindow!

func windowDidResize (notification: NSNotification) {
    window.delegate = self
    print("resized")
}


func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
        }

func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`windowWillEnterFullScreen:` and `windowDidEnterFullScreen:` are [NSWindowDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/) methods — to be able to use them, you just need to be the NSWindow's `delegate`. Your app delegate object or any other object could serve this purpose.

If you want to use custom animations during the transition, there are some other delegate methods such as `window:startCustomAnimationToEnterFullScreenOnScreen:withDuration:` that you could use.

You can also check `window.styleMask & NSFullScreenWindowMask != 0` to check whether the window is currently fullscreen.

Comment: Thank you, @jtbandes.  If I were to set my _AppDelegate_ class to be a `NSWindowDelegate`, could I just drag the Window from Interface Builder to the App Delegate to create the connection?  I think that's where I am struggling to figure this out.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to connect the `delegate` outlet in a xib using IB. (It's harder with storyboards.) Or you can do it from code. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: I see.  I am using a Storyboard, so perhaps that's where I am running into difficulty.  My searching led me to believe that setting `(NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window = self.window` in my AppDelegate (and then setting up the code there) would work.  Does that sound right?

Comment: No, you probably want `window.delegate = self`.

Comment: Sadly, I've not been able to get this working.  I updated my question with an example of what I'm trying to do.  I think I'm just confused as to how I define my Window Controller to connect to the AppDelegate.swift file.  Seems like maybe this is more complication than I was originally hoping.

Comment: I think the bigger problem is I just do not understand how to connect the Window delegate property to AppDelegate from the Storyboard.

Comment: You could either put this code in the NSWindowController subclass, or use [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690074/reference-main-nswindow-in-appdelegate-using-storyboard) (which I realize is where you got that earlier snippet).

Comment: Got it!  Now I need to learn about NSObservers and how to tell my table that the app entered full screen, but I did get the NSWindowController subclass working.  Thank you!!!